# C# File saving issues

Tags: c#, file, text, save

I'm trying to put all of these strings together into a path for my program to save a document in. Nothing fancy. but every time I go to save the file in debugging, it will create a folder named after the file and do nothing else. I feel like this is a simple issue, but I cant find how to fix it. Help please!

my code

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string strNotes = rtbNotes.Text.ToString();
   string strUser = txtUser.Text.ToString() + "\\";
   string strClass = txtClass.Text.ToString() + "\\";
   string strDate = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
   string strLocation = "C:\\Users\\My\\Desktop\\Notes\\";
   string strType = txtType.Text.ToString();
   string strFile = strLocation + strUser + strClass + strDate;
   string subPath = strFile + "." + strType;
    bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(subPath);
    if (!isExists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(strFile, strNotes);
}
```

Comment: Do you have check the paths result? subPath looks like a file not a dir

Comment: This code should create a directory with full name + type.  Then, it should create a file with no extension containing strNotes.  (unless an error occurs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your strLocation path is invalid:

C:\Users\My\Desktop\Notes\

Secondly you are passing entire file path (including file name / extension) into Directory.Exists so its actually checking to see to see if a **folder** named "12/12/13.txt" exists (you should simply pass the folder path).

You are then trying to write a file but passing what should be a directory path...

Are you using a debugger to step through your code? This would help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strNotes = "Some test notes.";
            string strUser = "someuser" + "\\";
            string strClass = "SomeClass" + "\\";
            string strDate = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            string strLocation = "C:\\Users\\My\\Desktop\\Notes\\";
            string strType = "txt";
            string strFile = strLocation + strUser + strClass + strDate; // ... this is: C:\Users\My\Desktop\Notes\
            string subPath = strFile + "." + strType; // .. this is: C:\Users\My\Desktop\Notes\someuser\SomeClass\26-10-2013.txt
            bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(subPath); // ... Checks directory: C:\Users\My\Desktop\Notes\ exists...
            if (!isExists)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath); // ... Creates directory:  C:\Users\My\Desktop\Notes\ ...
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(strFile, strNotes); // ... Writes file: this is: C:\Users\My\Desktop\Notes\26-10-2013 ...
        }
```

Comment: Actually, I think `strFile` is not a directory but a file missing it's extension.

Comment: Ah yes.. good spot... I copied and pasted the folder paths from the debugger, edited!

Comment: I went through it like you said and changed around the write and create folder strings and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug and watch the value of subPath. It looks like this is being set to the value of your intended file name but without the extension.

I think you should have had

```
string subPath = strLocation + strUser + strClass + strDate;
string strFile = subPath + "." + strType;
```